# Enviar imagen.jpg de un directorio en tablet a un directorio en mi PC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql-server

tengo una app mobile que toma una foto y me guarda la ruta en mi base de datos..
Los datos llegan a mi api en c# asp.net, y ella se encarga de enviar estos datos a mi base de datos.

ruta guardada de ejemplo :

file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.cordova.hellocordova/cache/1570208953904.jpg

Yo lo que necesito hacer es guaradar esa imagen en un directorio de mi pc...
es posible??

he estado probando en mi api de c# con System.IO.File.Copy(esa ruta, mi directorio)
pero me tira error, hay otra forma de hacerlo?

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("InsertarDatos")]
    public bool InsertarDatos([FromBody]datos dato)
    {
        //byte[] Fotobytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dato.foto);
        string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MiConexion"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        bool esta = false;
        string query = "INSERT INTO EnvioDeposito(idComprobante,fecha,foto,comentarios) VALUES (@idComprobante,@fecha,@foto,@comentarios)";
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idComprobante", dato.idComprobante);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dato.fecha);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foto", dato.foto);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comentarios", dato.comentarios);

        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            int filas = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (filas > 0)
            {
                esta = true;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
        if (esta == true)
        {
            string origen = dato.foto;
            string soloNombre = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(origen);
            string destino = @"\\10.100.59.21\Scanner\"+ soloNombre;
            try
            {
                //File.Move(origen, destinoPosta);
                System.IO.File.Copy(origen, destinoPosta, true);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        return esta;
    }
```

Asi invoco a mi metodo en api, utilizo Ajax en javascritp con jquery-mobile.. Muestro todo el codigo..

1- Primero convierto la imagen y obtengo su ruta

2- hago la llamada en ajax

3-Evento de boton

```js
var gImg;

function SacarFoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        gImg = imageData;
        $("#fotoCapturada").html('<img src="' + gImg + '" width="100%" >');
        //soloImagen = gImg.substring(gImg.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        alert(gImg);
        copyFile(imageURI, 'MiFoto.jpg', LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY) // no se que funcion cumple esto
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
}


function EnvioDatosDeposito(idComprobante, fecha, foto, comentarios) {
    var dir = "InsertarDatos";
    var datos = {
        idComprobante: idComprobante,
        fecha: fecha,
        foto: foto,
        comentarios: comentarios
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: api + dir,
        //processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;base64",
        data: JSON.stringify(datos),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(esta) {
            if (esta == true) {
                $("#pMensaje").html("Datos enviados satisfactoriamente.")
            } else {
                $("#pMensaje").html("Ha ocurrido un error en el envio de datos.")
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error en ajax");
        }
    });
}


function Enviar() {
    var txtidComprobante = $("#idComprobante").val();
    var txtfecha = $("#dtFecha").val();
    var txtcomentarios = $("#txtComentarios").val();
    EnvioDatosDeposito(txtidComprobante, txtfecha, gImg, txtcomentarios);

}
```

Comment: como invocas desde la tables a ese action de asp.net mvc ? programas la tablet usando xamarin o que libreria usas para realizar la llamada http al servidor

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ahi edite y agregue como invoco! Lo hago con ajax desde javascript

Answer (score 0):

No puedes acceder de forma remota a un archivo que esta local en el dispositivo, debes enviar como `byte array`

Para esto hay varias opciones, una podria hacer el `upload` del archivo

[Learn to Upload a file in MVC via Ajax](https://blog.eduonix.com/web-programming-tutorials/learn-to-upload-a-file-in-mvc-via-ajax/)

si tienes un model podrias usar

```
public class datos{
   //otras propiedades
   public HttpPostedFileBase file {get;set;}
}
```

entonces lo que debes armar desde codigo javascript es un

```
var data = new FormData();
```

para usar este en el data de la llamada ajax

Si necesitas un preview

[jQuery Image Upload with Image Perview](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1030349/jQuery-Image-Upload-with-Image-Perview)

vas a necesitas un `fileupload` tag de html oculto para poder mostrar la imagen, pero despues tomar el file desde este para armar el upload de ajax